# Cannot see GRUB GUI dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I used to have Ubuntu 18.04 along with Windows 10, then decided to format all my hard drive for a clean installation of Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10.

I deleted all partitions and erased the old boot entries using efibootmgr then installed Windows first with no problems. After installing Ubuntu my laptop would start with a black screen that said *"Booting in insecure mode"* but after a few seconds that should dissapear and show the GRUB menu. **It doesn't show any menu it only stays with the secure boot warning until the GRUB countdown finishes or I select a boot option and press enter.**

That means GRUB is actually working. I tried adding "nomodeset" to "quiet splash" with no success.
I also changed the boot order with grub-customizer and it worked so I can select the OS I want to boot.

Here's my /etc/default/grub file, I changed GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden" to "menu" in order to be able to select my boot options.

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="menu"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="10"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i8042.nomux=1 i8042.reset"
```

I'm using UEFI.

Ps: Sorry for my bad English!

Comment: Is your harddisk MBR of GPT partitioned? What are the settings of your BIOS? Secure, or UEFI with CSM (legacy), or Legacy only? Please update your question with the answer as well as the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/[abcd]`.

Comment: It is GPT partitioned, secure boot disabled, UEFI with CSM disabled (tried enabling both CSM and legacy and it booted in low resolution).

Here are the files containing the output of fdisk.
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PMpXI9cu_MmbFWIpCr7u34qnxSLkBv3d/view?usp=sharing)

[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wuAZ2l8tHaBU9OT4vOKPQnNCIDNsscgp/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: For future reference: `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda1` does not give relevant info, but fortunately you did include the output for /dev/sda. And your disk is GPT partitioned and your EFI partition has the right flags. Well done. The `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="menu"` looks right as well. You did not acknowledge that you did `sudo update-grub`. Did you actually not forget it?

Comment: Did you have trouble with your keyboard, mouse or trackpad for which you needed the `i8042` kernel options?

Comment: Lastly, your Ubuntu may have been installed in Legacy mode, causing your BIOS to display the 'insecure' message. Consider using [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)?

Comment: Indeed, multitouch wouldn't work without that. I used sudo update-grub. Boot repair didn't work either, Ubuntu is installed in UEFI mode. I'm considering reinstalling everything just in case something went wrong with the pendrive I was using.

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing Ubuntu 18.04 and GRUB worked without any problem. I guess there was some compatibility issues with the newest version on my laptop that gave me a lot of headaches.
So in case anyone else is having this same issue and tried all the solutions mentioned without success, **try going back to 18.04 or the version you had before.**

[Found someone with a similar problem here](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/fydbww/ubuntu_1910_grub_gui_not_visible/)

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: since it is already installed, try upgrading to 20.04 instead of installing it yourself... perhaps the upgrade process will handle the nuances... you know now that you can always go back to 18.04 if it doesn't work

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but I'm gonna stick with this version for now since I'm really delayed with all my tasks. Once I've got some free time I'll try upgrading and probably update this post with the results.

Comment: understood.... another option you might consider is installing 20.04 along side what you currently have now, if you have enough space, but this time DONT install grub... this way grub remains as is and you can go back into 18.04 and `update-grub` and have it add 20.04 to the existing grub menu...

Answer (score -1):

To fix this change:
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="menu"
To
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="shown"
Then type in the terminal `sudo update-grub2`
If this doesn't work reply and I'll try and fix this

Comment: That didn't work, sorry.

Comment: I see. Could you show me what your /etc/default/grub file reads?

Comment: @Miggyc: I did not know about `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="shown"` and I cannot find it in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Simple-configuration). What does it do?

Comment: It's more or less and allias to menu. You can keep it to menu. And if `sudo update-grub2` doesnt work. Try `sudo update-grub`